# (NET6+) Grant user read permission on certificate's private key

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Windows stores certificate's private keys as files, and you can use mmc.exe to give users read permissions on these keys. I need a way to do that programatically in NET6.

Microsoft have marked the `PrivateKey` property on the X509Certificate class as [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey?view=net-6.0) (since .NET 4.6) and the correct way is to use the [extension methods provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey?view=net-6.0).

However, the returned RSA key class does not contain a UniqueName property which I can then use to determine the filename of the private key, and thus grant a user read permission on it.

This question [Grant user permission to the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60541807/grant-user-permission-to-the-private-key) shows how it can be achieved using the obsolete property name.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved without using the `PrivateKey` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some luck with this:

```cs
// input: "X509Certificate2 cert"
RSACng rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() as RSACng;
string rsaKeyName = rsa.Key.UniqueName;
if (rsaKeyName == null)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    rsaKeyName = rsaCSP.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
}
```